# Java Iterator<E>, Inheritance of type E

Tags: java, inheritance, iterator

I discovered something rather interesting to me. Consider the following code:

```
// file: example.java
interface Interface1
{
    Iterator<Interface2> getIterator();
}

interface Interface2
{
}

interface Interface3 extends Interface2
{
}

class Class1 implements Interface1
{
    Iterator<Interface3> getIterator(); // Compiler throws error: type mismatch
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is this behavior documented somewhere?
2. Is this behavior right / intended?

Comment: you are expecting `Iterator<Interface2>` not `Iterator<Interface3>`

Comment: Your class should be abstract :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is documented somewhere, namely in [the Java Tutorial about generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). It is also intended.

If `B` is a subtype of `A`, then it is not the case that `SomeClass<B>` is a subtype of `SomeClass<A>`. The reason for this is the following. Suppose the following code would compile:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<B> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // if ArrayList<B> would be a subtype of ArrayList<A> 
    // this would be legal:
    ArrayList<A> list2 = list; 

    A element = new A();
    list2.add(element);
    // Uh-oh. Now list contains non-B elements.

    B b = list.get(0); // <--- ClassCastException
}
```

Then it would be possible to bypass the type parameter and add non-B objects to a list of B's. To cope with this problem, Java offers bound type variables: type variables can be bound above and below by the `extends` and `super` keywords. See the Java Turorial for information how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly to implement and interface you have to use implements not extends. Secondly when using generics you can use extends.
In the interface you have defined a method that would give you `Iterator<Interface2> getIterator();` but in the implementation you are doing `Iterator<Interface3> getIterator();`

Which won't work what you could do is use generics like this(Verified doesn't give compile error):

```
interface Interface1
{
    Iterator<? extends Interface2> getIterator();
}

interface Interface2
{
}

interface Interface3 extends Interface2
{
}

class Class1 implements Interface1
{
    public Iterator<Interface3> getIterator(){
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've implemented `Interface1`, which has a `getIterator()` method that returns an `Iterator<Interface2>`. That means that your implementing class needs its `getIterator()` method to return something of type `Iterator<Interface2>`; you're returning something of type `Iterator<Interface3>`.

The underlying problem you have here is that although `Interface3` extends `Interface2`, that does not mean that `Iterator<Interface3>` is a subtype of `Iterator<Interface2>`. Unfortunately the subclassing mechanism can't "see through" to type parameters.

It has annoying consequences. For instance, you can't write

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

It will give you a compiler error, because the expression on the right isn't assignment-compatible with the formal type parameter on the left.

Although `ArrayList<String>` is a subtype of `List<String>`, `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` isn't a subtype of `List<List<String>>`. You've got a similar thing going on here.